# Managing user files on Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I have been using Yii for a few months. I am working on a mid-size project that handles users, groups and some interaction between users (By example, users can make proposals in their groups, other users can comment on proposals, there are group moderators/administrators, and so on)

I am about to start a part of my project that involves managing user files. Basically I will handle 2 kind of files: images and pdfs. Images will be grouped in galleries, each having a name and description. Only the group administrators can create galleries (no restriction on the number of galleries) and upload files. Other users can see the pictures and files of their group only.

As I said, I have been working with Yii for some months, but I can't find clear information on user files management. I have a few questions:

1. What directory should I use to store files? Is there some kind of standard for this?
2. What facilities are provided by Yii for file management?

Hope you can give me ideas. Thanks in advance

EDIT: simplified the number of questions :)

Comment: That's six questions. You need to look more widely at how these things are achieved in any PHP app, then look to see what the Yii framework helps with. But don't store files in the database, just filenames.

Comment: @PaulGregory thanks for your advice. I just edited the post to simplify things

Answer (score 0):

For File management, yii have some extensions. This may be helpful for you.

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiifilemanagerfilepicker/
2. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cfile/
3. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiifilemanager/